# Emulating function static variables using threadstatic static fields?

Tags: c#, static, thread-safety, local-variables

For some static methods I realise it is extremely convenient to use a small array to temporarily store values during an operation. Said array is useful because you need indexing, but allocating that small array everytime the method is invoked.

Is *this* a good way to work around the lack of C-like static locals in C#?

```
[ThreadStatic]private static int[] staticregister = new int[4];

public static bool CoolStaticMethod(int[] largearray)
{
    //...
}
```

My assumption is that a method which can't call itself, either directly (recursive) or indirectly, can only be called singularly in a single thread, thus the fake static local should be declared thread-static and the problem is largerly solved.

Edit:

I must add that the contents of the register is garbage between method invocations.

Comment: **Yes** . [Just a filler to be able to comment]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is *not* what I would call a good workaround, no. It will *work* (assuming you are sure about the re-entrancy risks, i.e. not calling into itself, even via accidental events/callbacks/etc) - but...

In my *opinion*, it is stateful, **make it an instance**:

```
private int[] register = new int[4];
public bool CoolMethod(int[] largearray) {...}
```

and simply use different instance of `WheverTheTypeIs` for each context, i.e. the instance **acts** as the context. Just use a different instance per thread if you want context per-thread. This also allows usage with callbacks, parallelism, workers, etc to continue in the **same** context. Note that there are many frameworks that do not guarantee a single thread (WCF, ASP.NET, WPF for examples), and this is only going to increase as 5.0 introduces more `async`/`await`-oriented code.

If you are deeply tied to static methods, passing the `register` in as a second parameter would suffice too:

```
public static bool CoolStaticMethod(int[] largearray, int[] register) {...}
```

---

If the issue is the allocation of a 4-byte array:

1. that will usually be GEN-0, so cheap to collect
2. if you **really** want, use `stackalloc` and `unsafe` to avoid the allocation

For an example of "2":

```
public static unsafe bool CoolStaticMethod(int[] largearray)
{
    // not an array! this is raw data on the stack; DO NOT GO OUT OF BOUNDS!
    int* register = stackalloc int[4]; 

    register[0] = 1;
    register[1] = largearray[3];
    largearray[2] = register[0];
    ....
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion of passing the working buffer/register only complicates the design of client code that depends on the services of the static method.

Comment: @Cecil k; what about the last suggestion, if the problem is the allocation of a tiny array (which I ***really*** don't think you need to worry about, btw)

Comment: @Cecil plus, if you are allocation-minded, you could avoid that with a micro-pool; let me know if you want an example

Comment: To be honest, my original worry about allocation-lag and GC'ing is not really critical until I would have done some profiling to see that it actually could be a problem. The JIT and GC could, for what I know, see the usage pattern and allocate the array on the stack and pop it off on return.

Comment: @Cecil it won't do that (unless you stackalloc) - however, it will allocate on GEN-0 and die on GEN-0, which is really cheap to check. It depends on the usage, of course, but I wouldn't obsess about this unless it is called lots.